# can we make two same class with same name within same package but different .java programs

Tags: java

Can we make two class with same name within same package but different .java file.
Error is: "The type node is already defined"
here node is my class name.

Comment: Why do you have two classes named `Node` in the same package?

Comment: You need to change the package at list else jvm will get confused if which Node you want to use when ever someone request it.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible.  But only if you put the Java source code (with the same name / package) into separate source trees and compile them separately.

And then, if you want to use the compiled classes (with the same name / package) in one application, the application needs to use multiple classloaders with different classpaths, and other funky things.

And then, you run into all sorts of odd behaviors; e.g. exception messages like "cannot cast `foo.Bar` to `foo.Bar`"

Don't go there.  It is better to use different classnames and / or different package names.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a partial class usage. You can do it in .NET, not in JAVA but those classes will be same class on different file. Look at usage of partial class.

```
public partial class CoOrds
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public CoOrds(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public partial class CoOrds
{
    public void PrintCoOrds()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CoOrds: {0},{1}", x, y);
    }

}

class TestCoOrds
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CoOrds myCoOrds = new CoOrds(10, 15);
        myCoOrds.PrintCoOrds();

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
// Output: CoOrds: 10,15
```

Comment: This is Java, no partial classes there.